# Unable to save Data into a database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, combobox

I have a problem. I can't save the selected data from the combo box into a database. Can anyone provide any opinion or why it's like that?

Here are the codes that enables you all to understand more about my problem:

```
private void Create_LS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            cbStation.DisplayMember = "StationName";
            cbStation.ValueMember = "StationID";
            cbStation.DataSource = Setupctx.stations.ToList();

            cbLocation.DisplayMember = "LocationName";
            cbLocation.ValueMember = "LocationID";
            cbLocation.DataSource = Setupctx.locations.ToList();
        }
    }

private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            locationstation ls = new locationstation();
            ls.stationID = cbStation.SelectedIndex;
            ls.locationID = cbLocation.SelectedIndex;
            Setupctx.locationstations.AddObject(ls);
            Setupctx.SaveChanges();

            cbStation.SelectedIndex = -1;
            cbLocation.SelectedIndex = -1;

            MessageBox.Show("New Location Station Is Created");
        }
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your create method, why are you assigning `SelectedIndex` to ls.StationID and ls.locationID ? Selected index will give you the index of the selected item. I believe you are interested in [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem) or you may use [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text) Property.

EDIT:

Since your StationID and locationID are int, you may Convert the SelectedItem to int before assigning them to the fields. (*its better to use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to avoid the exception*)

```
int stationID = Convert.ToInt32(cbStation.SelectedItem.ToString());
int locationID = Convert.ToInt32(cbLocation.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

or

```
int stationID = Convert.ToInt32(cbStation.Text);
int locationID = Convert.ToInt32(cbLocation.Text);
```

Then

```
ls.stationID = stationID;
ls.locationID = locationID;
```

Comment: I tried using cbStation.SelectedValue but there's error with using ".SelectedValue"

Comment: @user1553650, my bad, it should be SelectedItem, not selectedValue

Comment: `stationID` and `locationID` are ints most likely and SelectedValue is a string. Convert the SelectedValues to int first:
    `ls.stationID = Convert.ToInt32(cbStation.SelectedValue);
    ls.locationID = Convert.ToInt32(cbLocation.SelectedValue);`
Of course this would only work if your `SelectedValue`s are populated with valid values.

Comment: There's still error stating: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'.

Comment: okkk, so StationID and LocationID are int, let me edit my answer

Comment: @rikitikitik, yup, .ToString will return the Text, or its better to simply use the Text